# what are the potential benefits of using YOCTO for generating custom distro and rootfs over using the ones supplied by vendor

Tags: linux, embedded, distributions, root-filesystem, yocto

I read about comparisons between buildroot and YOCTO project (google) regarding building rootfs and wanted to ask a more general question:

What are the potential benefits of building my own rootfs from scratch and building my own "OS distro" ,using YOCTO for example, instead of using the ones supplied by my embedded system vendor ,for example Nvidia with jetson SoCs.

I'm especially interested in the following aspects for comparison

- system security and OS hardening
- performance

I'm asking because I don't know "if its worth the effort" of learning and building these components by myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> using YOCTO for example, instead of using the ones supplied by my embedded system vendor ,for example Nvidia with jetson SoCs.

Does that fulfill your needs and have no more security attack surface than necessary? Does an nvidia eval board fit into your car's autonomous driving control box, physically? Does it connect to all your network interfaces, and to the car's control bus?

That's the thing. Embedded development is rarely "just run my python script on that SoC reference board". It's usually:

- take that SoC from the eval board build your own board around it, with own peripherals,
- write and supply drivers for the things you attach to your embedded board. After all, it's called *embedded*, because it's *embedded* in some other machinery.
- Write the application you want to deploy on that system.
- Develop a way to cross-compile it for that platform (you do **not** want to compile, say, chromium on an embedded platform. That takes literal weeks.)
- Develop a way to replace that software with a newer version, as you continuously develop it
- Write down a Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM), if you ever want to sell that system in the EU (see: RED directive. The US has similar requirements. You *must* know what software is in your device, explicitly, as a list.)
- If you're using any Free Software for which your customers can request the source code from you, keep the sources of exactly what you've put in your system around. Your customer has the right to that, and not some other version, or a version that hasn't been modified to work for your system or your appplication
- Develop a reproducible way to generate an image for the storage on your board. That's important – you will want to change something small in six months, and you must be 100% sure that all the tests that your whole system passed still pass, even if the guy who wrote the original build system is on vacation or can't remember.  Or retired. Or left your company.

Generally, vendor images don't do **any** of that.

OpenEmbedded offers

- a standardized way to build board support packages for your custom hardware, or even for vendor hardware, because more often than not,  vendor OSes really really suck
- a standard way to collect, keep up to date and integrate Linux kernel patches
- the possibility to generate an SDK with all the compilers, libraries, headers… necessary to develop software for the platform you just built
- a way to integrate software into the image that is robust, reproducible and not "oh, John knew which files to copy where, but he died"
- an easy way to generate packages out of these software recipes that can be replaced in the field
- SBOM generation from the same way you used to generate the image, so that it's actually complete and not "John thinks at worst he forgot to mention one or two small libraries that he used"
- Source packaging/archive generation (makes legal departments happy, because no competitor can sue them to stop distributing the hardware because it ships software whose FOSS license you're violating)
- A surefire way of baking images

So, the advantage is:

> The vendor image helps you understand the SoC well enough so you can build your own system out of it. It's never what you deploy to embedded devices in the end. OpenEmbedded helps you actually do the things that the vendor didn't do, which is what your customers pay you to do. Your customers do not pay you for putting a script on a reference board. They pay you for a production-ready, reliable, reproducible and legally compliant complete system.

Comment: Everything explained well, but actually, vendors like NXP or TI seem to maintain yocto layers for their SoCs and most vendors of embedded boards I know provide yocto repos that they use to bake their images, so there is not so much difference in the end. It's like comparing a cake to the recipe to bake that cake.

Comment: Well if you're in cake land, everything is sprinkles. But if you're going to bring some modified-it-barely-boots-but-has-vendor-GPU-driver Ubuntu to your own devices, or battling petalinux...

Comment: I simply don't meet any serious vendor offering anything else but yocto since years. And if I want to add something like a wireless module, it's also shipped with a yocto recipe. Maybe I just don't understand the question. Sorry.

Comment: @Philippos no need to be sorry! As you say, for many vendors that's true – but even if I get an eval board from say Qualcomm with a OE/Yocto BSP, that still doesn't make that board connect to my instrument cluster and CAN bus, right. So, even if it *is* a Yocto you get, the workflow typically is: get the tree (repo sync or whatever), make your modifications, and build your own Linux distro. It's not like especially Nvidia likes to make it look: yeah, you copy some files onto our Linux.

Comment: Unfortunally, getting started with yocto is not very inviting, so I understand promises about shortcuts can be tempting. Just if you mean it seriously, those shortcuts don't pay off.

Comment: @Philippos I totally sympathize. In many cases, if you're the vendor to your customers, your customers might totally be fine with just getting your OE-generated SDK and building their software with it, putting it in packages or directly deploying it. But, as said, I don't really even see that existence of a shortcut if, well, you're the vendor of your embedded hardware platform. Nvidia's not going to go in and integrate the driver for your funky octo-camera-link PCIe card and the CAN bus transceivers on your custom board into their reference image for a Jetson board.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed the title with a more clear question